# Data not ready when needed

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to load some data from the server before further processing. So have I have this function:

```
async load() {
    await this.reloadClients()
    this.findTimeSheets();
}

findTimeSheets() {
    for (const client of this.clients) {
        console.log('Client: ' + client.lastName);
    }      
}
```

This function gets called when clicking a button on the component.

I need the function this.timeSheets to wait until this.reloadClients is done processing, so the data is ready. This is the the reload function, it should load a list of clients and store it in this.clients:

```
reloadClients() {
    this.clientService.search({
        page: '0',
        query: 'assigner.id:' + this.selectedAssigner.id,
        size: '250',
        sort: ''})
       .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<Client[]>) => { this.clients = res.body; this.init(res.body); }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));
}
```

What happens now is that I need to click the button twice to get the correct data. So the loop in findTimeSheets() works after the second click (printing data to console).

My approach was to use await, but somehow this doesn't work.

As I'm new to Angular, I need some help resolving this.

Comment: ```return this.clientServiceSearch({...```

Comment: Won't help, as i'm subscribing to the result returned by the service.

Comment: It will. Makes the async call "wait". Otherwise it returns "undefined" before clientService gets to complete

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, how will I handle the subscription? When I return the service call, I cannot leave the subscription in the call.

Comment: The problem is, I need to map the data returned by clientService.search to this.client. For this purpose I call the service that returns an Observable and this cannot be marked async.

Comment: Why don't just move findTimeSheets() into your subscription.

Comment: @wannadream i need to load some more data after that, so for simplicity reason I'd like to keep that separated.

Comment: @wannadream: you know what? I still might do that, because this works fine. Is this good practice as well?

Comment: No matter what, you will need to pipe them one by one, executing synchronously. This is the simplest way.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I'll use it in the subscription, I hope i can further process the data that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have `await this.reloadClients()` However the function `reloadClients` is not `async`. So the await is useless.

## Fix

Make `reloadClients` async e.g.

```
async reloadClients() {
    await this.clientService.search({
        page: '0',
        query: 'assigner.id:' + this.selectedAssigner.id,
        size: '250',
        sort: ''})
       .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<Client[]>) => { this.clients = res.body; this.init(res.body); }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message))
       .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: replace return with await

Comment: Done. Because, I can see your preference for future expansion 

Comment: if you use the return keyword, you don't need the async keyword. but its a bit a lot tricky for the human eyes.

Comment: You cannot call `toPromise` on an RxJS subscription. Instead you could call `toPromise` first on the returned observable, and register the handlers that are now in `subscribe` in a `then` call.